# Linking external code in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors

I'm working with an external code in my project which I have access to the headers and the .cc files but I don't have any access to .dylibs. I'm getting some errors, related to link of the libs, that is described bellow.

This code runs perfectly well if I run it directly from the terminal. The problem only occured when I tried to incorporate it on my own project (that have other modules) in XCode. I guess that if I add the .dylib files to XCode it will solve the problem. However, I don't have the .dylibs. How can I put this code to run?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FACETRACKER::IO::LoadCon(char const*)", referenced from:
      mark(int, char const**) in main.o
  "FACETRACKER::IO::LoadTri(char const*)", referenced from:
      mark(int, char const**) in main.o
  "FACETRACKER::CLM::GetViewIdx()", referenced from:
      mark(int, char const**) in main.o
  "FACETRACKER::FDet::~FDet()", referenced from:
      FACETRACKER::Tracker::~Tracker() in main.o
      FACETRACKER::Tracker::Tracker(char const*) in main.o
  "FACETRACKER::Tracker::Load(char const*)", referenced from:
      FACETRACKER::Tracker::Tracker(char const*) in main.o
  "FACETRACKER::Tracker::Track(cv::Mat, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, int, int, double, double, bool)", referenced from:
      mark(int, char const**) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Re: "This code runs perfectly well if I run it in an isolated project". Doesn't that project have the `dylibs`?

Comment: I expressed myself badly. That other project that I mentioned is when I simply ran the code from the terminal. When I run directly from the terminal (using the command "make" and then "./file_name.cc" none error is generated.

Comment: Sure, but does that link to the `dylibs` in question?...

Comment: Running from the terminal I don't have any contact with the dylibs. So If that is being linked, probably it are happening implicity. The files that I have are describing in the project page on github: https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker/

Comment: I believe your issue is that you've not included the facetracker headers in your project, as [it doesn't link to any dylibs](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/FaceTracker/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dylib).